# Laravel maintenance mode --allow ip not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.7, maintenance-mode

I am trying to allow my public internet ip through maintenance mode in laravel on a vps.

Does the `--allow` command works over internet or does it work only on the localhost?
Because I cannot get pass the maintenance mode page with the following command:

```
$ php artisan down --allow=xx.xx.xx.xx (my public internet ip)
Application is now in maintenance mode.
$ php artisan up
Application is now live.
```

Comment: I have never tested this on remote website. But As I see [it should](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php#L51)
You can add a dummy route to verify  your IP: `Route::get('/what-is-my-ip', function(){ return request()->ip();});` and verify you're allowing the correct IP address

Comment: You are right, I did as you said and for some reason it shows another ip than what google `show my ip` shows. I am using cloudflare on the vps could that be a reason? If you post your comment as an answer I will vote it correct. Do you have any ideea why is the ip different? Thank you!

Comment: In my experience, IP services aren't that smart.. Some of them show (what I think is) my provider IP. I am on Ubuntu did and did an alias `myip='curl https://ipinfo.io/ip'`  I know that this own is correct.

Comment: `https://ipinfo.io/ip` shows me the same ip google does. But for some reason my vps `Route::get('/what-is-my-ip', function(){ return request()->ip();});` shows another ip. If I use that in maintenance mode it works but is very wierd that is shows a completely different ip than any other `show my ip` sites.

Comment: Weird indeed. Just be sure that Laravel doesn't see the same IP for everyone. If you'are behind cloudflare, I believe it will returns you the couldflare IP instead of the user IP. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cloudflare-and-user-ip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can verify the IP address your application see and allow it:

```
Route::get('/what-is-my-ip', function(){ 
    return request()->ip();
});
```

But be careful, if you're behind a content delivery network service, like *cloudflare*, you will see the IP of the service instead of the user. Which mean, everyone will have the same IP.

With e.g. *Cloudflare*, you can make it works by re-setting the correct user IP in `public/index.php`

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
}
```

source with more explanations: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cloudflare-and-user-ip

Comment: Just be careful blindly trusting anybody who sets the `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` header. You may want to look into Laravel's truster proxies options.